# Visual Studio - How to recompile only files with changed content, rather than changed by last modified?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a large project, which creates a header file out of some raw data every time it runs as part of the pre-build steps.

My issue is that even when the raw data is similar, VS will still recompile other files that used that header. Is there a way to re-define the criteria of what is considered to be modified by VS?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about instead modifying your pre-build step to generate to a temp file, compare that to the existing file, then only update the existing file if the temp is different?